# Is it possible to remove some checkboxes from tree view's nodes?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have made a tree view control in dialog box, using resource editor.

I have set the checkbox style with SetWindowLongPtr( ... ) function, the way Microsoft described.

Every node has checkbox this way, yet I need only some to have checkbox, and some to have nothing standing next to their text ( parent nodes do NOT have checkbox, only child or simple ones->ones without children ).

Can this be achieved by subclassing, or maybe with custom/owner draw or perhaps superclassing ?

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks. Also, please stop beginning every post with a thanks in advance for helping. It's not necessary here. :-)

Comment: I will never do that again, I promise, I am new here, and have typed some questions that way, hoping for question to be complete.
I am sorry.

Comment: Nothing to apologize for; my comment was meant to be helpful so you'd know in the future. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree control uses state images to draw the checkboxes. According to the docs on the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style:

> State image 1 is the unchecked box and state image 2 is the checked
>   box. Setting the state image to zero removes the check box altogether.

So something like this should let you remove the check box from a tree item:

```
TVITEM tvi;
tvi.hItem = hTreeItem;
tvi.mask = TVIF_STATE;
tvi.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
tvi.state = 0;
TreeView_SetItem(hWndTree, &tvi);
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but what if user clicks on the node?
The checkbox is shown then?

Comment: Try it and see! You could always sub-class the tree and throw away the clicks if they're on a checkbox that shouldn't be there.

Comment: OK, I will try it.
I will post my reply tomorrow.
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! God bless you!

To bad I can't upvote it :(((

So simple and so effective!

Comment: I have just got 15 rep points, so I gave you +1. Thank you again for your help. Can you help me with this problem, by any chance? It is really important to me, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888038/transparent-tree-view-control Thank you.