# Transparent tree view control

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a tree view with transparent background, using pure Win32 API.

After reading documentation from MSDN I was able to successfully create it, but there is nothing saying on how to make it transparent. Google doesn't help either, since examples are in MFC, and they do not create transparent background, but rather change tree's color by using TreeView_SetBkColor API or with TVM_SETBKCOLOR message.

**Just for an example**, I have created window like this one below:

[image]

And I have added tree view as a child window like this:

[image]

My question is: How do I make tree's background transparent so the picture behind it can be seen ?

### EDIT #2:

If anybody else has a better answer/suggestion, please post it, but at this point I will accept Joel's solution.

---

Comment: Respond to the `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message and customize the background there.

Comment: Mr.Chen, can you please be more specific, since I am a beginner ? Can you provide more detailed instructions of what your idea is ? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: One way is to apply [How do I get a radio button control to render its text transparently?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/06/28/10031289.aspx) to tree view controls. Another is to forward the paint to your parent, then return a null brush. I'll leave to you learn more about these techniques. It would take too long to explain them here.

Comment: Mr.Chen can you provide some links then ? I know I am boring but please understand me, I am desperate...

Comment: I thought I included a link already. Here it is again: [How do I get a radio button to render its text transparently?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/06/28/10031289.aspx)

Comment: @RaymondChen - For my own education, I tried doing this with the `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message with no luck (see the commented-out code in the `WndProc` function in my answer). Note that the code in my answer does return the `NULL_BRUSH` but I did try it with your `CreatePatternBrushFromFile` function, and it still didn't work right. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Joel `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` requires you to do three things, but you did only one. You also didn't draw the background, which was sort of the point of the exercise. Set the text color, the background color, *draw the background*, set the mode to transparent, then return a null brush so the background won't get erased.

Comment: @RaymondChen - I see no difference when I do that. I have updated the commented-out code section in my answer with code that does all of the things you say a `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` requires. When I run it like that (taking out the subclassing code), the tree view still paints text with a white background and still creates visual artifacts when scrolled. These artifacts correct themselves when the main window is resized, for example, but until then they are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably stop deleting and re-adding this question.

**Edited: This is the best I've been able to come up with. I can't emphasize enough what a hack this code is and how easy it would be for it to break. However, this combines my efforts with Jonathan's comments into something that sort of works. It flickers, and it's ugly, but it more or less does what was requested.**

```
// Making these globals is bad practice, but I'm not trying to show perfect
// practice here.

HDC     hDCMem;          // memory DC for background bitmap
HBITMAP hBmp;            // the background bitmap
WNDPROC oldTreeWndProc;  // old WndProc for tree view
HWND    hWndTree;        // HWND of the tree view

// Subclassed tree view WndProc

LRESULT CALLBACK TreeWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_VSCROLL:
    case WM_HSCROLL:
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case TVM_INSERTITEM:
    case TVM_DELETEITEM:
    case TVM_SELECTITEM:
    case TVM_EXPAND:
    case TVM_ENSUREVISIBLE:
        {
            // For a whole bunch of messages that might cause repainting apart
            // from WM_PAINT, let the tree view process the message then
            // invalidate the window. This is a brittle hack and will break as
            // soon as tree views handle some other kind of message that isn't
            // included in the list above. Fundamentally, tree views just don't
            // seem to support this kind of transparency.
            //
            // If you use this in production, expect to get bug reports about
            // weird background artifacts when somebody scrolls the window
            // some way you didn't think of or that didn't exist at the time
            // the code was written.

            LRESULT result =
                CallWindowProc(oldTreeWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            return result;
        }

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            ::CallWindowProc(oldTreeWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

            COLORREF treeBGColor = SendMessage(hWnd, TVM_GETBKCOLOR, 0, 0);

            // This shouldn't return -1 because it should have been set in the
            // parent WndProc to an explicit color.

            assert(treeBGColor != ((COLORREF)(-1)));

            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

            RECT rect;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
            HWND hWndParent = GetParent(hWnd);

            POINT pt;
            pt.x = rect.left;
            pt.y = rect.top;
            ScreenToClient(hWndParent, &pt);
            rect.left = pt.x;
            rect.top = pt.y;

            pt.x = rect.right;
            pt.y = rect.bottom;
            ScreenToClient(hWndParent, &pt);
            rect.right = pt.x;
            rect.bottom = pt.y;

            int cx = rect.right - rect.left;
            int cy = rect.bottom - rect.top;

            HDC hdcMemTree = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            HBITMAP hComposite = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDCMem, cx, cy);
            hComposite = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemTree, hComposite);

            // Blt the background bitmap to the tree view memory DC

            BitBlt(
                hdcMemTree, 0, 0, cx, cy, hDCMem, rect.left, rect.top, SRCCOPY);

            // TransparentBlt what the tree view drew for itself into the tree
            // view memory DC (this part overlays the tree view window onto the
            // background).

            TransparentBlt(
                hdcMemTree, 0, 0, cx, cy, hdc, 0, 0, cx, cy, treeBGColor);

            // Blt the memory DC back to the screen with the composite image.

            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, cx, cy, hdcMemTree, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            hComposite = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemTree, hComposite);
            DeleteObject(hComposite);
            DeleteDC(hdcMemTree);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return ::CallWindowProc(oldTreeWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

// Main window WndProc

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HDC hDCDisplay = GetDC(NULL);
            hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDCDisplay);
            ReleaseDC(NULL, hDCDisplay);

            // This code loads the bitmap from a file. You will need to replace it with
            // something that copies your image into the memory DC at the right size.

            hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(
                NULL, _T("Test.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

            if (hBmp == NULL)
            {
                MessageBox(hWnd, _T("Failed to load bitmap"), _T("Error"), MB_OK);
            }

            hBmp = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hDCMem, hBmp);

            hWndTree = CreateWindowEx(
                0,
                WC_TREEVIEW,
                _T(""),
                WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)10000,
                NULL,
                0);

            if (hWndTree == NULL)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to make tree view"), _T("Error"), MB_OK);
            }

            oldTreeWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(
                hWndTree, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)TreeWndProc);

            // Make sure the background color for the tree view is not the
            // same as any of the selected colors so that selections don't
            // get messed up by transparency. If this feels like a hack,
            // that's because it is.

            COLORREF selectedBGColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);
            COLORREF selectedFGColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT);

            COLORREF treeBGColor = (selectedBGColor + 1) % 0x00ffffff;

            if (treeBGColor == selectedFGColor)
            {
                treeBGColor = (selectedFGColor + 1) % 0x00ffffff;
            }

            SendMessage(hWndTree, TVM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, treeBGColor);

            // Add a bunch of dummy items to the tree view just for testing.

            TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis;
            ::ZeroMemory(&tvis, sizeof(tvis));
            tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
            tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
            tvis.hParent = TVI_ROOT;

            TCHAR buffer[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            {
                _stprintf(buffer, _T("Item %d"), i);
                tvis.item.pszText = buffer;
                tvis.item.cchTextMax = _tcslen(buffer);
                SendMessage(hWndTree, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tvis);
            }
        }
        return 0;

        // Leaving the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT stuff in here to show how that would
        // seem to work. I tried it, and it doesn't really work all that well.
        // Initially, the background shows through, but when you scroll the
        // window, it doesn't redraw the background. It just seems to do a
        // a ScrollWindow call and blts the background upward. Also, the
        // background of the tree view items stayed white even with the code
        // to change the background mode to TRANSPARENT.

    //case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    //    {
    //        HDC hdcCtrl = GET_WM_CTLCOLOR_HDC(wParam, lParam, message);
    //        HWND hWndCtrl = GET_WM_CTLCOLOR_HWND(wParam, lParam, message);

    //        if (hWndCtrl != hWndTree)
    //        {
    //            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    //        }

    //        SetTextColor(hdcCtrl, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    //        SetBkColor(hdcCtrl, RGB(0xff, 0xff, 0xff));
    //        SetBkMode(hdcCtrl, TRANSPARENT);

    //        RECT rect;
    //        GetWindowRect(hWndCtrl, &rect);

    //        POINT pt;
    //        pt.x = rect.left;
    //        pt.y = rect.top;
    //        ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
    //        rect.left = pt.x;
    //        rect.top = pt.y;

    //        pt.x = rect.right;
    //        pt.y = rect.bottom;
    //        ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
    //        rect.right = pt.x;
    //        rect.bottom = pt.y;

    //        int cx = rect.right - rect.left;
    //        int cy = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    //        BitBlt(hdcCtrl, 0, 0, cx, cy, hDCMem, rect.left, rect.top, SRCCOPY);

    //        return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    //    }

    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // 960 x 540 is the size of the image I used for testing. Adjust for
        // your own image.

        ::BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 960, 540, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_SIZE:

        // Positioning the tree view somewhere on the parent that is not the
        // upper left corner.

        MoveWindow(hWndTree, 20, 20, 100, 100, TRUE);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        hBmp = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hDCMem, hBmp);
        ::DeleteObject(hBmp);
        ::DeleteDC(hDCMem);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As I mentioned before, the `hDCMem` contains the original pre-stretched bitmap and has to be accessible to the subclassed `WndProc`. This will only work as-is if the original bitmap is drawn at (0,0) in the parent. And as the image shows it's pretty awful to look at.

It also has a few other flaws (and there are probably more than I've listed here):

1. It assumes tree views are always drawn with a solid background color. As buttons have shown, Microsoft may change their appearance at whim, so customize at your own risk.
2. It assumes you know all the messages that cause repaints on a tree view. This is not a good assumption. Even if it's true now, there's nothing to prevent it breaking with some future update to the tree view control, simply because this isn't documented to work and it's playing around with code that doesn't belong to the application - the built-in tree view `WndProc`.
3. Even if this is a good way to do this, it probably isn't a good idea to recreate the bitmaps and memory DCs on every `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: Thank you Joel SO MUCH! I have deleted those questions, because I believe that this one describes my problem the best. I appreciate everything you have done so far, and I believe that your solution will work, but I also believe you are right about its flaws, so I ask you this, before I start implementing it: Is there a better way to solve my problem? One that doesn't eat up that much memory ?

Comment: You can avoid this problem by switching the order - paint your background first, and then call the tree's `WM_PAINT` handler to have it paint on top. You also need to override `WM_ERASEBKGND` to stop the tree erasing what you've painted. However I've been down this exact path and there are lots of traps for young players - the tree does painting in response to lots of other messages besides `WM_PAINT`. For example, opening a node will cause the tree to manually repaint (and animate) the new items appearing, so you end up having to trap a whole bunch of other messages (e.g. `TVM_EXPAND`) too.

Comment: I don't really have a self-contained block of code I can post for you unfortunately; I suggest you start with Joel's example and go from there. The link Raymond Chen posted may be of some use but the tree is far more complicated than a radio button and the fact that he just blindly posted that link as if it's a simple solution makes me think he has never actually tried to do this himself.

Comment: You'll need to handle the following messages as they can cause the tree to do painting without going through `WM_PAINT` : `TVM_INSERTITEM`, `TVM_DELETEITEM`, `TVM_SELECTITEM`, `TVM_EXPAND` and `TVM_ENSUREVISIBLE`. The method I use is to trap those messages, turn off redrawing in the tree using `WM_SETREDRAW`, pass the message through to the original procedure, then turn redrawing back on and force a repaint of the tree background.

Comment: Additionally, any messages that cause the tree to scroll will require you to forcibly redraw the entire background (so, `WM_VSCROLL`, `WM_HSCROLL`, `WM_KEYDOWN` with cursor keys, etc..). To be honest, by the time I finally got my solution working I wished I had just written my own tree control as I think it would have been a lot quicker.

Comment: OK, one more edit that incorporates Jonathan's comments. I will also note that I tried Raymond's method of handling `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` without much luck. I would **strongly** encourage you to read the comments in the code, to understand exactly what this code is doing, and to understand exactly why it's not that great an idea to use it in production. I will also say at this point, I am done with this question. It has been a bit of a learning experience for me, as well, but at this point I've spent about as much time as I can on it. Best of luck :)

Comment: One final note: I left the `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` handler returning the `NULL_BRUSH` stock object even though that's not what Raymond's link to his blog shows. I did try it with the pattern brush and the results were different but not better. You still get the visual artifacts when the tree view scrolls, and the text is not rendered transparently, even if you set the foreground and background colors before setting the background mode.

Comment: Joel, I have just tried your code and it works. A few questions, since I might be able to accept your solution, but let me state this: My tree view displays fixed data ( additional nodes will not be added ); it fits the window the way it is ( there will be no scrolling ); so I ask you if there will still be flicker ? Just one problem I have found though: after I move the parent window to the left ( so a part of the tree is no longer on screen ), nodes get erased. I have tried to InvalidateRect in main window handler for WM_SIZE/WM_ERASEBKGND but had no luck. Any thoughts ?

Comment: One or more of the blts fails because the visible portion of the window is smaller than the code is assuming it is. You will have to find some way to figure out the visible part of the window. I only get a problem on my machine when I resize the main window so that part of the tree view is cut off but not when it goes off screen. If partial hiding of the window off-screen or by another window is causing you problems on Windows XP, for example, it may not be trivial to get around this. The tree view shape may be irregular.

Comment: To your question about flicker, it probably won't be bad if you aren't scrolling. That's where I saw the worst, but I'm not going to promise you it won't flicker for some other reason. It flickers because it repaints the tree view on screen before rendering it over the bitmap in memory and blting it back to the screen. Any time you write to the screen twice quickly == flicker. Because I don't think it can be said enough, this code is a total hack and has so many points that could break it that I personally would probably write my own custom tree view before using this in production code.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write custom tree view? It must be hard task for a beginner but maybe some tutorial exists? Your solution works, but we both know, unfortunately,that it can not satisfy commercial standards :(

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Once you have gained enough experience with programming for Windows, such a thing will probably not be too difficult for you. But it would be fairly time-consuming, and I don't have one ready-made. I don't know what your requirements are, but you could probably do something like this pretty easily with WPF, but you would be in .NET land at that point, not to mention you would have to basically rewrite your application.

Comment: Damn... Thank you, then. I will probably replace tree view with something else then...

Comment: At the end of the day, for all controls, you need four basic things: the right data structure, the right API, some painting code, and some input-handling code. It's all fairly straightforward, but if you're under a time crunch I can understand that you may not have time to come up to speed on all of those things. If another solution would work just as well, that's ok, too :)

Comment: My mistake. I was operating from faulty memory. Treeview always draws an opaque background behind the text and ignores your `SetBkMode`. So you're stuck with solid color background for text.