# Removed checkbox reappears in treeview node when spacebar is pressed

Tags: c++, winapi, checkbox, treeview, keyboard-shortcuts

I have used the accepted solution [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798463/is-it-possible-to-remove-some-checkboxes-from-tree-views-nodes?lq=1) to remove *checkbox* from a *treeview node* in my `WM_INITDIALOG` handler.

Upon loading, *tree* has a proper look. After I select the node and click on the place where *checkbox* would be, nothing happens ( *checkbox* does not appear ) which is the correct behavior.

However, if I select the node **and press** <kbd>spacebar</kbd> the *checkbox* is automatically added to the node.

Here is the `WM_INITDIALOG` handler that illustrates the problem:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // get treeview handle

        HWND TreeView = GetDlgItem( hDlg, IDC_TREE1 );

        /************ enable checkboxes **************/

        DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong( TreeView , GWL_STYLE);
        dwStyle |= TVS_CHECKBOXES;
        SetWindowLongPtr( TreeView , GWL_STYLE, dwStyle );

        /************ add items and subitems **********/

        // add root item

        TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis = {0};

        tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
        tvis.item.pszText = L"This is root item";
        tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
        tvis.hParent = TVI_ROOT;

        HTREEITEM hRootItem = reinterpret_cast<HTREEITEM>( SendMessage( TreeView ,
            TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &tvis ) ) );

        // and here is an example of removing a checkbox 

        TVITEM tvi;
        tvi.hItem = hRootItem ;
        tvi.mask = TVIF_STATE;
        tvi.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
        tvi.state = 0;
        TreeView_SetItem( TreeView, &tvi );

        // add firts subitem for the hTreeItem

        memset( &tvis, 0, sizeof(TVINSERTSTRUCT) );

        tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
        tvis.item.pszText = L"This is first subitem";
        tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
        tvis.hParent = hRootItem;

        HTREEITEM hTreeSubItem1 = reinterpret_cast<HTREEITEM>( SendMessage( TreeView ,
            TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &tvis ) ) );

        // now we insert second subitem for hRootItem

        memset( &tvis, 0, sizeof(TVINSERTSTRUCT) );

        tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_STATE; // added extra flag
        tvis.item.pszText = L"This is second subitem";
        tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
        tvis.hParent = hRootItem;

        HTREEITEM hTreeSubItem2 = reinterpret_cast<HTREEITEM>( SendMessage( TreeView , 
            TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &tvis ) ) );
    }
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is interesting quote from MSDN:

Version 5.80. Displays a check box **even if no image is associated with the item.**

Perhaps this is the cause of my problem?

I ave tried handling [`TVN_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set items state or again removing the *checkbox* but had no success.

### EDIT #2:

I have subclassed the tree, the way member *Jonathan Potter* suggested, and it worked:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK TreeProc( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, 
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData )
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            // reject spacebar if tree node doesn't have checkbox
            if( wParam == VK_SPACE ) 
            {
                HTREEITEM ht = TreeView_GetSelection( hwnd );

                TVITEM tvItem;

                // Prepare to receive the desired information.
                tvItem.mask = TVIF_HANDLE | TVIF_STATE;
                tvItem.hItem = (HTREEITEM)ht;
                tvItem.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;

                // Request the information.
                TreeView_GetItem( hwnd, &tvItem );

                // reject if it's not checked, or pass default value otherwise
                switch( tvItem.state >> 12 )
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBeep(0);
                        return FALSE;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    default:
                        return ::DefSubclassProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );
                        break;
                }               
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        ::RemoveWindowSubclass( hwnd, TreeProc, 0 );
        break;
    }
    return ::DefSubclassProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

### END OF EDIT

### QUESTION:

How can I properly remove *checkbox* from a *tree node* **so it never appears again** ?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: Sub-class the control, intercept the space key, and don't pass it through if the focus is on an item you don't want to have a checkbox.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have tried to implement your suggestion but have failed. I have edited my post with the subclassing code. Code for testing whether node has no checkbox/is checked/is not checked  works. I have also retrieved the text of the focused node to make sure I test the right node with `TreeView_GetSelection()` and the text was correct. It seems that tree first checks/uncheckes node **and only then** I get `WM_CHAR`. Can you please review the short code snippet I submitted just so we can verify my conclusions or correct my mistakes if there are any? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: Try trapping `WM_KEYDOWN` rather than `WM_CHAR`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! If you post this as an answer I will upvote and officially accept ( that I must subclass and intercept `WM_KEYDOWN` ). Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub-class the control, intercept the space key via `WM_KEYDOWN`, and don't pass the message through if the focus is on an item that you don't want to have a checkbox.

Comment: I have finally awarded the bounty. Thanks again for your help. Best regards until next time.

Comment: Happy to help as always!